# Paramiko how to specify Folder path

Tags: python, paramiko

```
import paramiko
import os
import sys

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
paramiko.util.log_to_file('U:\\Temp\\paramiko.log')
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())


ssh.connect('172.18.24.234','/TestBTEC/',22,'btectest','M3j0Stanf0rd')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("mkdir abc")
stdout.readlines()
```

This is obviously throwing back errors. What is the proper way to set the home directory on the remote server for user btectest

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting you can also specify parent directory as userprofile as below 
import os

```
abc_dir = os.path.join('%UserProfile%','abc')
cmd = "mkdir %s" % abc_dir
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you are passing to SSHCient.connect() are incorrect (at least for paramiko 1.6+).  Your connect() call should look like this:

```
ssh.connect('172.18.24.234', username='btectest', password='...')
```

or if you explicitly include the port:

```
ssh.connect('172.18.24.234', 22, 'btectest', '...')
```

Once connected, you should already be in the home directory of the user "btectest", as can be seen with this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")
stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
ssh.connect("172.18.24.234", 22, 'btectest', 'M3j0Stanf0rd')
File "C:\Documents and Settings\tyoffe\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 316, in connect
 self._policy.missing_host_key(self, server_hostkey_name, server_key)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\tyoffe\Application Data\Python\Python27\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 85, in missing_host_key  raise SSHException('Unknown server %s' % hostname)
SSHException: Unknown server 172.18.24.234
>>> ssh.connect('172.18.24.234', 22, 'btectest', 'M3j0Stanf0rd')

Comment: I commented out  ssh.load_system_host_keys() and am no longer getting the exception error. However passing the pwd command I am not able to view the directory.